# What does it mean to see dead relatives in dreams

Tags: dream

Recently, for sometime my friend have been dreaming of his dead relatives. This is happening for a few days now. Usually it's 3-4 relatives whom he dreams about.

So I would like to know why is he dreaming of dead relatives again and again, does this mean something and is there any way to get rid of these dreams?

Comment: Maybe he thinks about them all the time and dreams just show what you think all day, if this isn't the case, then what are those relatives telling to him?. You can visit [Vedanta and Philosophy](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38640/vedanta-and-philosophy) for a chat on this topic.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria - One thing I can assure you is that he probably never thinks much about them because neither he was close to them nor he spent more time with them. Moreover, all of them passed away long time back. In dreams relatives are not particularly saying anything to him, its just casual talk.

Comment: It looks like those relatives were in his subconscious so once he saw them in dreams, he got alert thinking it might mean something and started thinking about them every day and that probably led to repetitive dreams.

Comment: This can definitely indicate something. i have checked a relevant book that i possess & that discusses auspicious/inauspicious dreams but could not find any relevant info in it.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria - Could be a possibility, but if he dreams of one relative and started thinking of them, then why is he seeing the other person in his dreams who is not even his immediate relative.

Comment: Seeing the same people multiple times in dream definitely indicates something. Chanting the Holy name of Lord Vishnu takes away such bad dreams. He is thus called 'DuSwapnaNashna'; One who destroys bad dreams. Its also better to take help of some reliable astrologer or priest.