# What does it mean to see dead relatives in dreams?

Tags: identification-request, dream

[Agni Purana](https://archive.org/stream/AgniPuranaChowkhambaSurbharati/Agni%20Purana%20-%20Chowkhamba%20Surbharati#page/n482/mode/1up) provide details about various dreams and their meaning. Similarly, [Markandeya Purana](https://archive.org/stream/markandeyapurana/markandeya_purana_hindi#page/n167/mode/1up) and [Vayu Purana](https://archive.org/stream/VayuPuranam/Vayu--puranam#page/n137/mode/1up) also mention many dreams and their meaning.

But I couldn't find the meaning of seeing dead relatives in dream. Can someone please provide the meaning of it? Also, if possible please specify if it has different meanings if one see

- ancestors or siblings (younger/elder) or descendants
- who died naturally or due to untimely death

PS: Please note that I am not asking any personal advice here but the scriptural references of such dream.

Comment: That question can be edited to remove personal details. Repetition of same question is not encouraged. This is a duplicate.

Comment: This site might be interesting. Although slightly unrelated - http://srath.com/k%E1%B9%9B%E1%B9%A3%E1%B9%87a-teachings-dreams/

Comment: Same question closed as personal advice [What does it mean to see dead relatives alive in dreams](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/17893/5212).